# Pause/stop/resume selenium batch execution

Tags: selenium

Any tools available in the market or is it possible to pause/resume/stop selenium batch execution. Pausing script from command prompt is much helpful.

Comment: Please elaborate more ?

Comment: When running scripts from bat file in a selenium framework . Is it possible to pause script?

Comment: at what level you want to stop the script. when you are creating a bat file , you can include pause

Comment: tried pause in bat file it stops the script completely but not resuming

Comment: you can do something like :  start cmd /c <command>  for resume operation.

Comment: still not working ,typing ctrl+c in cmd prompt while running script ,no matter what terminate batch job(y/n) it is terminating

Comment: Does this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50845190/can-i-make-selenium-pause-for-input-and-resume-on-a-trigger/50961793#50961793